# Visual Studio Code auto completing

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual studio code but that auto complete stuff not working rn,

For example when i am write "<!Doc" and press the tab it was write all head,body and metas but it's not working rn, i tried CTRL+M not worked, delete visual studio and install again not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the normal HTML Template in VS Code,
try to use "!".
If you you need other Code Snippets take a look in the Extension Market and install additional extensions.